# rspec model attribute change not saving properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using factory girl to create a model with inventory_count = 3. In my test, I want to test a case for when inventory_count = 0..so here's what I did:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @piece = FactoryGirl.create(:piece)
  @lineup = @user.lineup
end

it 'should have status \'Waiting List\' if the piece doesn\'t have available inventory' do
  @piece.available_count = 0
  @lineup.pieces << @piece
  piece_lineup = @lineup.piece_lineups.find_by_piece_id(@piece.id)
  piece_lineup.set_status
  piece_lineup.status.should == 'Waiting List'
end
```

I put a debugger after @piece.available_count = 0 and it is = 0, but when it gets down to the next line it switches back to the old value. I tried adding a .save to @piece but it still didn't work. Am i doing something wrong? Should I be creating the new value model in factorygirl instead of trying to do it on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be better practice to write:

```
@piece = FactoryGirl.create(:piece, :available_count => 0)
```

to create a `piece` model with its count already 0.

Also, you're question begins mentioning `inventory_count`. Did you actually mean `available_count`? Just want to make sure you didn't have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The change isn't making it to the DB. Try

`@piece.update_attributes!(available_count: 0)`

EDIT: To skip the callback that is resetting the available_count, use `update_column(:available_count, 0)`

Comment: Just write how you normally would. This is a new way of writing hashes that was recently introduced. What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: i'm using the newest versino of ruby...odd...it seemed to work once but now the same test is failing...

Comment: it just isn't setting the value of available_count == 0

Comment: Is it failing validation? If so, just use update_attribute(:available_count, 0) to skip validations.

Comment: I found the problem. In my model code, I frequently update the available_count as a before_update so it keeps resetting it to what it "should" be. Do you know of a way where I can force it to test it and skip the model update of available_count?

Comment: See if my EDIT fixes the problem

Comment: nope, didn't work. nothing seems to be working. the value keeps changing back. I even tried creating a second user, assigning it the piece (which should decrement @piece.available_count) and then testing for it, and it was still not setting available_count correctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13865/discussion-between-cdesrosiers-and-matthew-berman)